# uniform convergence & puntual convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness, uniform-convergence

Which are all the differences between uniform convergence and puntual convergence of a sequence of functions {$f_n$} in a compact space?

I know one difference between them, the uniform converge of $f_n$ to $f$ doesn't depend of the point x, whereas puntual convergence does.

Does anyone know about other differences between the convergences?

Comment: uniform convergence preserves properties like continuity and also interchanging of differentiation/integration operators with limit operator is possible

Comment: Also I think there's no big difference with their definitions. Confuses me

Comment: There is actually. Because puntual convergence just gives u the behaviour of the functions at one point but not on the whole. For example take $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1] $ where $f_n(x)=x^n$ then work out the puntual limit of $f_n$ and u'll see the limit function suddenly becomes discontinuous. Uniform convergence implies the graphs of the functions will get closer and closer.

Comment: "puntual"? Is that a thing? "pointwise" is what I've always heard it called.

Comment: @Nick I think it's the same..it's just my bad translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were to understand the difference in the requirements of the two modes of convergence of a sequence of functions. Let $X \neq \varnothing$; let $(M,d)$ be a metric space; let $f_{n}: X \to M$ for all integers $n \geq 1$; let $f: X \to M$. Then the sequence $(f_{n})$ is said to converge pointwisely to $f$ iff for every $x \in X$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some integer $N \geq 1$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $d(f_{n}(x),f(x)) < \varepsilon$. Clearly, pointwise convergence of $f_{n}$ to $f$ requires simply that at every point $x$ of $X$ the sequence $(f_{n}(x))$ of **real numbers** converges to the real number $f(x)$. From this you can also tell why mathematicians use a word such as "pointwise" or "punctual" to modify such a mode of convergence. On the other hand, the sequence $(f_{n})$ is said to converge to $f$ uniformly iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some integer $N \geq 1$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $d(f_{n}(x),f(x)) < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in X$. Now uniform convergence of $(f_{n})$ to $f$ instead requires that $f_{n}$ should be arbitrarily close to $f$ if $n$ is large enough.

If $X, M := \mathbb{R}$, then intuitively graphically you can see that uniform convergence of $(f_{n})$ to $f$ requires that the graph of each $f_{n}$ with $n$ large enough should be arbitrarily close to the graph of $f$. However, pointwise convergence of $(f_{n})$ to $f$ does not require that much.